# Why vote for close for my " Tumbleweed" question?

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-close, unanswered-questions, tumbleweed-badge

I've asked

[Tuple relational calculus, equivalence of queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720859/tuple-relational-calculus-equivalence-of-queries)

> Please suggestion to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm unclear on the topicality of relational tuple calculus on Stack Overflow<sup>1</sup>, the trigger message for your question is here:

> Can you explain in formal way please ?

You're basically looking for a textbook answer to this problem, which I doubt makes sense here.

I could *very* easily be wrong, but that's at least how it comes across.  If you were looking for clarity as to why your solution might be incorrect, then that'd be another matter altogether.

If you don't wish for this to be the case, consider rewording this question so that it doesn't come across as, "Answer this like a textbook please?" sort of question.

<sup>1:  I remember this vaguely from college...it was only ever useful in theory.  I'm really not sure it's on topic here.</sup>